# Artifactory doesn't work after restoring nuget packages

Tags: artifactory

When a team member restores nuget packages using donet, artifactory enters a loop with the errors below until the memory overflows.

The problem only happens when he adds in his Nuget.Config the tag **protocolVersion="3"**

```
    <add key="Company" value="https://repo.company.com/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/rdi-nuget-virtual" protocolVersion="3" />
```

In the tests we noticed that the use of the protocolversion=3 tag causes this.

This tag is necessary because the download of the file is much faster

Anyone have an idea what it could be?

Could you help me please?

logs below

Version jfrog: 7.29.8 rev 72908900

```
2022-01-11T14:00:57.263Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [6cdecc92eaf486c7] [.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:136] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-43] - Sending HTTP error code 403: Download request for repo:path 'nuget-remote-cache:.nuGetV3/feed.json' is forbidden for user: 'lcunha'.
2022-01-11T14:00:57.264Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [6cdecc92eaf486c7] [etV3VirtualAndRemoteCommon:274] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-43] - Failed to download resource in repo: nuget-remote, at url: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. HTTP STATUS CODE: 403
2022-01-11T14:00:57.264Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [6cdecc92eaf486c7] [etV3VirtualAndRemoteCommon:133] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-43] - Failed to convert artifactory url (https://repostaging.companysoftware.com:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/company-nuget-virtual/registration-semver2) to original remote url for repo: nuget-remote, package: xunit.core
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)

2022-01-11T14:01:56.786Z [jfrou] [ERROR] [2016c910242342cc] [external_topology.go:82 ] [main ] - Failed fetching external topology from Access: Get "http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/topology": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2022-01-11T14:02:04.871Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [7f3fb3a30ade9665] [local_topology.go:268 ] [main ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2022-01-11T14:02:09.877Z [jfrou] [ERROR] [7f3fb3a30ade9665] [local_topology.go:128 ] [main ] - periodic send heartbeat failed for 4 consecutive times. Last error: failed sending heartbeat information to Access: failed closing Access grpc client: closing heartbeat client and waiting for response timed-out

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 3974"...
2022-01-11T14:02:11.185Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [5a89519a8048b91d] [local_topology.go:268 ] [main ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
2022-01-11T14:02:11.196Z [jfrou] [ERROR] [79bb63bc55c1ed15] [external_topology.go:82 ] [main ] - Failed fetching external topology from Access: Get "http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/topology": read tcp 127.0.0.1:55970-127.0.0.1:8040: read: connection reset by peer
2022/01/11 14:02:11 httputil: ReverseProxy read error during body copy: read tcp 127.0.0.1:56788->127.0.0.1:8045: read: connection reset by peer
2022/01/11 14:02:11 httputil: ReverseProxy read error during body copy: read tcp 127.0.0.1:56788->127.0.0.1:8045: read: connection reset by peer
2022/01/11 14:02:11 httputil: ReverseProxy read error during body copy: read tcp 127.0.0.1:56788->127.0.0.1:8045: read: connection reset by peer
2022-01-11T14:02:11.208Z 35[jfob ] [WARN ] [1ed879c85a5af005] [access_join.go:70 ] [main ] - Refreshing platform config change events gRPC stream - target server is unavailable - if issue persists check communication with access [access_client]
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactory.sh: line 359: 3974 Killed $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
```

**Can you share your setup?**

-The application server is the CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

-MySQL as backend Database

-Also, we are using the Apache as reverse proxy to apply the SSL certificate.

**How are you running Artifactory?**

-The Artifactory is container based: releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.29.8

**How much resources to you give it? Memory and CPU**

- The server has allocated:

  ```
            2 vCPU

            16 GB RAM

            SSD
  ```

**What are the java memory settings? Mostly interested in heap settings (Xms and Xmx)?** 
We are using the standard configuration. No changes were made in the Xms and Xms parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Artifactory v7.x? You may refer to our [System Requirements wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-RequirementsMatrix) for the recommended hardware based on your environment.

Also, from on the error message shared, it looks like the user does not have proper permissions hence we see 403 errors. Please do validate and assign the required permissions to the user and let us know the results.

```
Sending HTTP error code 403: 
    Download request for repo:
       path 'nuget-remote-cache:.nuGetV3/feed.json' is forbidden for user: 'lcunha'.
```